# Создать принимающий параметр в DataSet, узнать id без его переоткрытия

Tags: delphi, база-данных, firebird

Я использую *DataSet* для вставки записи в БД. Но также я хочу в запросе вставки возвращать **id** этой записи. Для этого я написал запрос свойстве *InsertSQL*

```
insert into FEATURES_ETALON
  (CIMP_MRA, CODE_CLASSIF, DEVICE_METHOD, DIAPASON_MAX, DIAPASON_MIN, FORMAT, ID, MEASURAND, MEASURING_APPARATUS, PARAMETER_CONDITION_MEAS, UNIT, VALUE_AMBIGUITY, VALUE_CONDITION_MEAS)
values
  (:CIMP_MRA, :CODE_CLASSIF, :DEVICE_METHOD, :DIAPASON_MAX, :DIAPASON_MIN, :FORMAT, GEN_ID(GEN_ID_FEATURES_ETALON, 1), :MEASURAND, :MEASURING_APPARATUS, :PARAMETER_CONDITION_MEAS, :UNIT, :VALUE_AMBIGUITY, :VALUE_CONDITION_MEAS)
returning ID into :ID
```

но т.к. параметра *ID* нет, то в месте «into :ID», вылазит ошибка: «"**Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 5, column 19.
?.**»

Далее в событии *AfterPost* (DataSet), я хочу присваивать значение полю *ID*

```
procedure TFMain.DataSetAfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
   DataSet.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger := DataSet.ParamByName('ID').AsInteger;
  DataSet.Transaction.CommitRetaining;
end;
```

- Как мне создать параметр в DataSet?
- я в правильном месте присваиваю ID?

Answer (score 1):

Назначать `id` можно в `BeforePost`, `AfterInsert`, `OnNewRecord`. Тогда и возвращать его не понадобится, потому что оно уже будет лежать в соответствующем поле.
Может быть ещё `BeforeInsert`, но не уверен, что к этому времени DataSet уже в режиме редактирования.

Для установки id в обработчике события понадобится запрос для извлечения следующего значения генератора. Он выполняется в обработчике.

Delphi раньше вроде сам умел пользоваться генераторами interbase? Надо было только указать из какого генератора брать значение для поля. И всё. Никаких обработчиков событий. Сейчас не так или это всё не правда?

Событие же `AfterPost` случается после того, как запись сохранена в базе данных. Тут уже поздно что-то присваивать.
Думаю, если бы сработал Ваш обработчик, то он выписал бы ошибку `DataSet is not edit or insert mode` на первой же строчке.

Что касается `returning`, то Delphi его по ходу не поддерживает (не припомню такого). Ведь это относительно недавняя фича firebird, а delphi всегда ориентировался на interbase, где не было этого `returning` и ставка на предварительную генерацию id. Придётся писать свои компоненты UpdateSQL.

Обычно ещё существуют возможности узнать какой же id был использован в новой записи. Для этого надо после записи в базу (в обработчике `AfterPost`) выполнить специальный запрос. Но как потом передать это значение назад в DataSet? Та же ошибка `DataSet is not edit or insert mode`.

Comment: Тогда, как было, так и оставлю. В принципе запрос выше возвращает нужное ID, но мне кажется что уже поздно оно доходит, чтобы вставить его в dataset.

Comment: По правде говоря, мне показалось, что ошибка "Invalid token..." говорит о том, что запрос составлен не правильно. и не выполняется он в принципе. 100% рабочий вариант в первых 2х абзацах. Для облегчения себе задачи уточнить 3й.

Comment: да, запрос неправильный только если использовать "*...into :ID*" без предварительного создания параметра в *DataSet*, так он работает. Но тут мне подсказали другой вариант решения получения ID - через метод **GeneratorField** (*IBDataSet*) с "*Apply Event = OnPost*", как раз для меня подходит

Comment: @Konstantin78 Хорошо, что нашли этот вариант. Как раз на него и хотел навести в 3ем абзаце.